# If URL Contains x Then Do Y in Twig / Craft Template?

Tags: templating, pagination, seo

I've got a website that has a resource center, news center and blog where each of those sections has a high quantity of assets that can be filtered by topic / type / date, etc. Additionally, due to the quantity of assets, we're using pagination to spread the assets across multiple pages.

All of the filtering and pagination creates a variety of worthless but currently crawlable URLs that we'd like to hide from the search engines.

I'm attempting to deploy the meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" tag to all of the paginated / filtered URLs while keeping the overview pages indexed. It seems that the most logical way to do that is based on a consistent URL string that appears in both pagination and filtering instances.

How can I add a rule within my template that will insert the meta tag based on whether or not a string exists in the current URL appearing in a user's browser?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string you're looking for is part of the URI segment, then something like:

```
{% if (craft.request.getSegment(3) == 'mySpecialKey') %}
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
{% endif %}
```

(Adjusting the 3 for whichever part of the segment it's actually in.

Or if it's part of the querystring, then use `craft.request.getParam('mySpecialKey')`.

Comment: You could also compare against [`getPageNum`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.request#getPageNum) in the conditional: `{% if (craft.request.getPageNum() != 1) %}`.

Comment: Thanks, gents! The portion of the URL that I'd like to target is actually a ? as part of a query string. Essentially, I'd like the rule to be applied whenever a query string exists.The getSegment method above seems to work at targeting a portion of a static URL but is not working when I try to target the ? in the query string. Same for the getParam method. Is there a way that I can make a similar if / then rule based on whether or not a query string exists?

Comment: Both `getParam('key')` and `getQuery('key')` should return from the querystring.

Comment: Thanks, Brad! I was able to get it working with your help.